# How to dispose SignalR statechanged callback function

Tags: angular, callback, connection, signalr, dispose

I am trying to implement lock future for preventing multiple edits on the same document in my Angular 5 web application. I have created my hub and connection in Angular services to reuse it in multiple components. As soon as the user logged in, I will create my proxy and connection which are stores in service. In each component inside the OnInit, I have a code that runs on "connection.onStatChanged" to invoke lock command to the hub. Because I am storing the connection in service, after I leave one component still the event listener for that component is listening to the event of "onStateChanged" for the connection. I want to clear the callback function in ngOnDestory of each component. If the connection lost with server and user change page to another page, still the event listener is running and as soon as connection establish again, it tries to lock that document!

```
this.dataService.connection.stateChanged((change) => {
    if (change.newState === $.signalR.connectionState.connected) {
      this.registerSignalR();
      this.dataService.authProxy.invoke('lock', this.authNo, this.userService.userName, this.userService.userId);
    }
    this.connectionStateChange.next(change.newState);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by using the following code, But I am not sure is it the best way?

```
ngOnDestroy() {    
   this.dataService.connection.stateChanged(null);
}
```